# Echoing returned value from previous function

Tags: php, mysql

```
function report_test() {

$color = "blue";
$name = "John";

mobile_test($color, $name);
echo $columnid;
}

function mobile_test($color, $name) {

-snipped Insert MySQL Query-
$columnid = 5;
return $columnid;
}
```

Hopefully the example above portrays what I'm attempting to do. Globalising the variable columnid isn't an option in this scenario due to other various reasons. I also do not want to alter the `mobile_test($color, $name)` function. I find that if I echo the function instead the MySQL Insert Query is ran twice, meaning two sets of the same results gets entered into the database.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to `echo` out the **`return`** value from `mobile_test()` inside of `report_test()`. The easiest way to do this is to simply `echo` out `$columnid`  **inisde** of `mobile_test()`. When you call `mobile_test()` from `report_test()`, the `echo` statement will be called as well, and the value will be outputted:

```
function mobile_test($color, $name) {
  ...
  $columnid = 5;
  echo $columnid;
  return $columnid;
}
```

There's also the possibility to make use of PHP's **[short tag syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)** (as `<?= mobile_test(); ?>`), assuming you want to echo the `return` of the function directly, and not do anything else with it.

Note that if you leave in the `return` value (`return $columnid;`), you'll be able to use this value directly as a comparison in the `report_test()` function:

```
if (mobile_test($color, $name) === 5) {
   echo "The column ID is 5" /* This line will be triggered */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do this:

```
function report_test() {

$color = "blue";
$name = "John";

$columnid = mobile_test($color, $name);
echo $columnid;
}
```

you need to store the returned value from `mobile_test()` as a new variable. This won't need to change the `mobile_test()`